# How to use root.findall with AND condition

Tags: python, xml, xpath

XML be something like this:

```
<Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Fruit">
        <Content>Apple</Content>
</Section>
        
<Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Meat">
        <Content>Beef</Content>
</Section>
```

I want to print content when SectionID in level 1 = Food and SectionID in level 2 = Fruit. I couldn't find tutorial using XPath with AND condition.

```
def main():
    tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for section in root.findall("./Section/[SectionID='Food']"):

    and

    for section in root.findall("./Section/Section/[SectionID='Fruit']"):

    print(content)
```

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: @daniel-haley Sorry for the late reply, I went on a vacation. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `and` in xpath, but I don't think you need it in this case. I think you just need to put your two xpath's together...

```xml
.//Section[@SectionID='Food']/Section[@SectionID='Fruit']/Content
```

Full example...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO  # using StringIO to simulate reading a file instead of a string

xml = """<doc>
<Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Fruit">
        <Content>Apple</Content>
    </Section>
</Section>
        
<Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Meat">
        <Content>Beef</Content>
    </Section>
</Section>
</doc>"""

doc = StringIO(xml)
tree = ET.parse(doc)

for content_elem in tree.findall(".//Section[@SectionID='Food']/Section[@SectionID='Fruit']/Content"):
    print(content_elem.text)
```

Printed output...

```
Apple
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I went on a vacation. Thank you, it works.